# python, split string into array after second character

Tags: python, arrays, split

I'm capturing a file with the following content:

```
*> <'Char><'Char><'space><'string>*
```

example:
**Original File**

```
Fs .file1
 M /home/file2
?? /home/file3
M  /home/file4
 D /home/file5
```

I'm trying to get each line into a list and get always one array with 2 columns. I tried

```
line.split(' ')
```

but it is not working since an empty char might happen on the first or second position of each row.

so, I need to do this split after the second character, meaning the result of the above file will be:

```
['Fs','.file1']
[' M','./home/file2']
['??','./home/file3']
['M ','./home/file4']
[' D','./home/file5']
```

It would be also acceptable if the empty character on the firl array index is trimmed

```
['Fs','.file1']
['M','./home/file2']
['??','./home/file3']
['M ','./home/file4']
['D','./home/file5']
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because SO is not a code writing service

Comment: @BhargavRao, in fairness it is not overly obvious how to do it

Comment: @BhargavRao They did say they tried `split(" ")`  and showed the input and expected output so I think it is a fair  question, I don't think they expected the file part just how to split correctly which would not be  that obvious to some people.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rsplit` presuming the contents all look like you  have in your question:

```
lines ="""Fs .file1
 M /home/file2
?? /home/file3
M  /home/file4
 D /home/file5"""

for line in lines.splitlines():
    # splitting once on " " starting from the right 
    # side keep all whitespace on the left elements
    print(line.rsplit(" ",1))

['Fs', '.file1']
[' M', '/home/file2']
['??', '/home/file3']
['M ', '/home/file4']
[' D', '/home/file5']
```

So simply use the following in your own code:

```
print [line.rstrip().rsplit(" ",1)for line in f]
```

Or as @jonClements suggests use `line.rpartition(' ')[::2]` to always make sure we get two elements per list:

```
print [line.rpartition(' ')[::2] for line in f]
```

Comment: To guarantee that you get two elements after the split (I imagine it's plausible to *not* have flags), then `line.rpartition(' ')[::2]` can be used...

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 3 characters before the filename (fixed width) then do the simple way:

```
flags, filename = line[:2], line[3:]
```

There is no need to do fancy instead of the right thing.